# How to get a specific date?

Tags: java, calendar

I have the output

> Mon Feb 19 02:43:13 EST 2018

Which I've obtained from

`System.out.println(new Date());//+ some adjustments with the calendar obviously.`

I was curious how I would 'reload' the 'date' from the given output

> Mon Feb 19 02:43:13 EST 2018

So if I wanted to refer to the date again when I reload my program, I want it to parse the String and set the date based off of those parameters, is this a good way to handle this?

Comment: Google for "how to parse a Date in Java". This question has been asked a million times.

Comment: I did look on google, don't need to be a dick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best idea I would have is storing the date in a document, I have done this in a similar fashion. I had taken the Unix epoch time, stored the value, then had a converter bring it back to the human readable version. Not too complex.